# Is there a way to show which argument is bad using a try except statement?

Tags: python

I don't know anything about python myself, this question is something I came up with in 2hrs after helping him with his code.

This code was his code he wrote for class:

```
# Assignment 4-1

import sys

def calcavg(grade1, grade2, grade3):
    average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3
    return(average)

def getletter(score):
    if (100 < score) or (score < 0):
        lettergrade = "Bad Score"
    elif score >= 90 :
        lettergrade = "A"
    elif score >= 80 :
        lettergrade = "B"
    elif score >= 70 :
        lettergrade = "C"
    elif score >= 60 :
        lettergrade = "D"
    else:
        lettergrade = "F"
    return(lettergrade)

def printresults(average, lettergrade):
    print("Average: " + str(average))
    print("Letter Grade: " + str(lettergrade))

try:
    grade1 = float(sys.argv[1])
    grade2 = float(sys.argv[2])
    grade3 = float(sys.argv[3])
    average = calcavg(grade1,grade2, grade3)
    lettergrade = getletter(average)
    printresults(average, lettergrade)

except:
    print("Error. Grade must be numeric.")

#else:
#   average = calcavg(grade1,grade2, grade3)
#   lettergrade = getletter(average)
#   printresults(average, lettergrade)
```

To me the else at the end seemed redundant, so I moved it with the try. My thinking was it shouldn't try to run the code and then if it doesn't fail it should, it should try to run and give the results unless something is wrong. I think the way he had it would slow down in bigger scripts.

This lead to us looking at his previous lessons where they tried and if it didn't fail it'd try something else. I don't have that example, but its something like

```
try:
except:
else:
    try:
    except:
    else:
        done
```

We worked together to write a script that would try both and tell you which one failed without trying something else if the first try didn't fail and still tell you which one failed. Its easy to try both and print an error if one fails, but telling you which one was the error was where we got tripped up.

This is the code I wrote at some point:

```
import sys

test1 = sys.argv[1]
test2 = sys.argv[2]

try:
    int(test1),int(test2)

except:
    if test1 != int:
        print("test1 error")
    if test2 != int:
        print("test2 error")
else:
    print("Ok")
```

This fails if one is wrong but only prints "test1 error test2 error" or if the second if is an elif: "test1 error". Most of the problems we got stuck on is it just does not care for lines like `test1 = int` or `test2 != int` even for

```
try:
    isinstance(test1, int),isinstance(test2, int)
except:
    if not test1:
        print("test1 error")
    if not test2:
        print("test2 error")
```

it seemingly ingores if test1 is false and proceeds to print "Ok".

Comment: Your advice regarding `else` clauses was entirely wrong, which makes sense, since you don't know Python. Similarly, your use of `isinstance`, `not`, and `!=` doesn't match what they actually mean in Python.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I knew I could be wrong, Im more familiar with things like bash where I would cut down on similar functions. Im not trying to hinder my friend in any way, we both learned a lot and I think it led to a bigger problem (this one), where we made the same mistakes trying to get it to differentiate anyway. Curious: is moving the else to part of the try block actually wrong? I know there is cases you'd still want to use else, especially if you had another outcome.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in comments, that your understanding of python is a bit wrong. I would suggest you to clear some of your basic concepts further.

However, to answer your problem, I think you should *raise custom exception*. They will be very useful in your case. In the below code I have covered how can you test which parameter failed:

```
try:
    grade1 = float(sys.argv[1])
    grade2 = float(sys.argv[2])
    grade3 = float(sys.argv[3])
    average = calcavg(grade1,grade2, grade3)
    lettergrade = getletter(average)
    printresults(average, lettergrade)
except Exception as ex:
    print("Error. Grade must be numeric.")
    print(ex)
```

So, you just have to add `except Exception as ex:`, this will print the actual cause of the exception.

Comment: So would this have been the correct way to tackle the issue in the example code we worked on? (I put my computer away to go to bed) `try: test1 = int(sys.argv[1]), test2 = int(sys.argv[2]) except Exception as ex: print(ex)` That would print test1 or test2 respectively? Pardon me trying to format that in a one liner on my phone.

Comment: @ZenRen yes it will tell you which variable caused the problem, what was the problem and if you want to know the full stack and stuff you can do this also. But, As you are a beginner so i will recommend you to stick with these two or now.